# What is the best way to implement URL validation in flutter where the user should be able to enter only one URL instead of multiple?

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

I want to implement URL validation in flutter where the user should be able to enter only one URL in a filed instead of multiple URL's separated by commas, empty spaces.. What is best way to implement this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you just try to parse it with Uri.parse or Uri.tryParse - and see if it worked?

Answer (score 1):

```
String replacedString = urlStringHere!
         .replaceFirst("http:", "##")
         .replaceFirst("www", "##")
         .replaceFirst(".com", "##")
         .replaceFirst(".net", "##");
if (replacedString.contains("http") ||
    replacedString.contains("www") ||
    replacedString.contains(".com")) {
       return "You can enter only one url";
      } else {
        return null;
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will also consider other answers/approaches before implementing.